# Ho to make all elements inside a container responsive?

Tags: html, css

Can i please get some help with the code i have in order to make all the elements inside a container maintain their position and scale down when resizing the browser or when viewing the page from smaller devices like an ipad or a phone.
Currently when the browser width is getting smaller, the elements inside the container are being rearranged.
Big thank you in advance.

HTML:

```
              <div class="container-fluid">
  
               <div class="flex-container1">
                 <div class="progress-bar-ai">
                    <div data-size="20" class="progress-ai"></div>
                </div>
                <div><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/icons/Illustrator.png" width="70" height="auto" alt="..." /></div>
                <div><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/icons/Dreamweaver.png" width="70" height="auto" alt="..." /></div>
                <div class="progress-bar-dw">
                    <div data-size="20" class="progress-dw"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
  
              <div class="flex-container2">
                 <div class="progress-bar-ae">
                    <div data-size="20" class="progress-ae"></div>
                </div>
                <div><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/icons/After Effects.png" width="70" height="auto" alt="..." /></div>
                <div><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/icons/Photoshop.png" width="70" height="auto" alt="..." /></div>
                <div class="progress-bar-ps">
                    <div data-size="20" class="progress-ps"></div>
                </div>
              </div> 

              <div class="flex-container3">
                <div class="progress-bar-xd">
                   <div data-size="20" class="progress-xd"></div>
               </div>
               <div><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/icons/Experience Design.png" width="70" height="auto" alt="..." /></div>
               <div><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/icons/InDesign.png" width="70" height="auto" alt="..." /></div>
               <div class="progress-bar-id">
                   <div data-size="20" class="progress-id"></div>
               </div>
              </div> 

             </div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex-container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-container1>div {
  margin: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.progress-bar-ai {
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  left: 30px;
  background-color: #310000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.progress-ai {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 3px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 14px;
  float: right;
}

.progress-bar-dw {
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  right: 30px;
  background-color: #480036;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.progress-dw {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 14px;
}
.progress-dw.play-animation {
  background: #FF40F0;
  width: 40%;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in;
  animation: load 2s normal;
}
.progress-ai.play-animation {
  background: #EEA808;
  width: 90%;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in;
  animation: load 2s normal;
}



.flex-container2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-container2>div {
  margin: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.progress-bar-ae {
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  left: 30px;
  background-color: #11005D;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.progress-ae {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 3px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 14px;
  float: right;
}

.progress-bar-ps {
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  right: 30px;
  background-color: #001D33;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.progress-ps {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 14px;
}
.progress-ps.play-animation {
  background: #00A7FF;
  width: 50%;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in;
  animation: load 2s normal;
}
.progress-ae.play-animation {
  background: #9D90FA;
  width: 65%;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in;
  animation: load 2s normal;
}



.flex-container3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.flex-container3>div {
  margin: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.progress-bar-xd {
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  left: 30px;
  background-color: #480036;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.progress-xd {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 3px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 14px;
  float: right;
}
.progress-bar-id {
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  right: 30px;
  background-color: #49001C;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.progress-id {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 14px;
}
.progress-id.play-animation {
  background: #FF0A61;
  width: 75%;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in;
  animation: load 2s normal;
}
.progress-xd.play-animation {
  background: #FF40F0;
  width: 60%;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in;
  animation: load 2s normal;
}
```

Comment: Have a go at making all those px values into relative (to the viewport etc) values. But you may find that you really need a different design for very small viewports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `flex-wrap: wrap` from the `.flex-container1`, etc rules. This will stop the elements from wrapping to new lines. Add a rule for the `<img>` elements so that they can scale down.

```css
.flex-container1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-container1>div {
  margin: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.progress-bar-ai {
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  left: 30px;
  background-color: #310000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.progress-ai {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 3px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 14px;
  float: right;
}

.progress-bar-dw {
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  right: 30px;
  background-color: #480036;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.progress-dw {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 14px;
}
.progress-dw.play-animation {
  background: #FF40F0;
  width: 40%;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in;
  animation: load 2s normal;
}
.progress-ai.play-animation {
  background: #EEA808;
  width: 90%;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in;
  animation: load 2s normal;
}



.flex-container2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-container2>div {
  margin: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.progress-bar-ae {
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  left: 30px;
  background-color: #11005D;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.progress-ae {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 3px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 14px;
  float: right;
}

.progress-bar-ps {
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  right: 30px;
  background-color: #001D33;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.progress-ps {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 14px;
}
.progress-ps.play-animation {
  background: #00A7FF;
  width: 50%;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in;
  animation: load 2s normal;
}
.progress-ae.play-animation {
  background: #9D90FA;
  width: 65%;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in;
  animation: load 2s normal;
}



.flex-container3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.flex-container3>div {
  margin: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.progress-bar-xd {
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  left: 30px;
  background-color: #480036;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.progress-xd {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 3px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 14px;
  float: right;
}
.progress-bar-id {
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  right: 30px;
  background-color: #49001C;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.progress-id {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 14px;
}
.progress-id.play-animation {
  background: #FF0A61;
  width: 75%;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in;
  animation: load 2s normal;
}
.progress-xd.play-animation {
  background: #FF40F0;
  width: 60%;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in;
  animation: load 2s normal;
}

.img-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="flex-container1">
    <div class="progress-bar-ai">
      <div data-size="20" class="progress-ai"></div>
    </div>
    <div><img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/70/70" width="70" height="auto" alt="..." /></div>
    <div><img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/70/70" width="70" height="auto" alt="..." /></div>
    <div class="progress-bar-dw">
      <div data-size="20" class="progress-dw"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-container2">
    <div class="progress-bar-ae">
      <div data-size="20" class="progress-ae"></div>
    </div>
    <div><img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/70/70" width="70" height="auto" alt="..." /></div>
    <div><img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/70/70" width="70" height="auto" alt="..." /></div>
    <div class="progress-bar-ps">
      <div data-size="20" class="progress-ps"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-container3">
    <div class="progress-bar-xd">
      <div data-size="20" class="progress-xd"></div>
    </div>
    <div><img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/70/70" width="70" height="auto" alt="..." /></div>
    <div><img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/70/70" width="70" height="auto" alt="..." /></div>
    <div class="progress-bar-id">
      <div data-size="20" class="progress-id"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works.
Not sure how to explain this, but when the images are scaling down, they are fixed on their top margin somehow and they are sort of not arranged anymore with the progress bars next to them when they reach a smaller size. hope this makes sense.
Is there any way to keep them in place while the scaling down is happening ?
Thank you

Comment: Yep! In all the `.progress-bar-*` rules, prepend `div` to the selector, like `.progress-bar-ai` → `div.progress-bar-ai`. Then replace `top: 45px` with `margin-top: 65px`. Add `align-items: end` to all the `.flex-container` rules.

Comment: Thank you, will give it a try in a few minutes.
Also, can we control the ammount of scaling for the the images ?
Let's say now the images are a bit small when seen from a phone, how to stop the scaling at about 50% or another value until i get it right ?
Thanks again, much appreciated :D